# Loop in loop to temporarily modify calcs after specific iteration

Tags: r, loops

I'm doing calculations within a loop. I want to change the calculations when the iteration reaches a certain number. I have been trying unsuccessfully to run another loop within the first one to alter the calculations as needed. This may be an entirely incorrect approach. Suggestion welcome.

```
u=seq(0,4,length=10) 
v=dexp(u,rate=1) ##exponential decay 
w=0.87*v #the vector that I want to apply to calculations
x=25 #the iteration where I want to start altering the main loop calcs, from here to here + length(w


test=data.frame(seq(1,150,2),seq(151,300,2))##some data
for(y in 1:(length(test)))
{
res=test[,1]*test[,2]###the main calculation of the loop, simplified
for(z in x:x+(length(w)))###on iteration x=25 start this secondary loop after running the first loop
{
res[z+1]=res[z]-(res[z]*w[z])   
}
}
plot(cumsum(res))
```

This does not behave as intended, I'm looking for a drop in the increase or a flattening at x=25 on the plot.

Comment: A couple of problems with this code... `length(test)` returns `2`, since the length of a data.frame is the number of columns it has; `25:25+10` returns `35`, since the `:` operator is evaluated before the `+` operator (so you need `25:(25+10)`). Many functions in R are vectorised, so we can do away with these loops entirely.

Comment: It would be nice if you'd include your expected output (make the example data shorter if that helps).

Answer (score 0):

The following changes calculations from iteration 25 onward:

```
u=seq(0,4,length=10) 
v=dexp(u,rate=1)
w=0.87*v 
test=data.frame(seq(1,150,2),seq(151,300,2))
res <- numeric(length=75)

for(y in seq(nrow(test)))
{
  ifelse(y < 25, res[y] <- test[y,1]*test[y,2], res[y] <- NA) 
}
res[is.na(res)]<-res[24]

res2 <- as.data.frame(res)
res2 <- sweep(res2,MARGIN=2,w,`*`)
res2 <- as.numeric(as.matrix(res2))

res <- append(res[1:24],res2[25:75])

plot(cumsum(res))
```

What are you trying to do with w? I've recycled the vector from iteration 25.